# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when calling DolbyAudioProcessing.getDolbyAudioProcessing

Tags: android, dolby-audio-api

I have integrated Dolby_audio_plugin_api_v1.1.1.0 into my Android app and am seeing this stack trace in a handful of cases:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dolby.dap.DsClientManager$AppActivityLifecycleCallbacks
       at com.dolby.dap.DsClientManager.(DsClientManager.java:196)
       at com.dolby.dap.DolbyAudioProcessing.(DolbyAudioProcessing.java:143)
       at 
com.dolby.dap.DolbyAudioProcessing.getDolbyAudioProcessing(DolbyAudioProcessing.java:125)
       at com.houseofhighfives.saddest_trombone.Main.onCreate(Main.java:44)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Following the examples on the Dolby dev site, this is the call that tries to initialize the DolbyAudioProcessing instance:

```
mDolbyAudioProcessing = DolbyAudioProcessing.getDolbyAudioProcessing(this, PROFILE.MUSIC, this);
```

According to Crashlytics, all instances were on a Samsung GT-S5360B or GT-S5360L, running Android 2.3.6.

Very minor thing, given how infrequent it is, but it makes me curious. Has anyone else seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

So this turned out to be a because the AppActivityLifecycleCallbacks is an ICS API Level interface. I should have been doing SDK_LEVEL check before calling DolbyAudioProcessing.getDolbyAudioProcessing(). –  mmcmahon